# why read -n from fifo file will lost data in shell

Tags: bash, shell, fifo, mkfifo

First I make a fifo

```
mkfifo a.fifo
```

Then I echo something to it

```
echo 1 > a.fifo
```

Open another terminal, and also add sth to it

```
echo 2 > a.fifo
```

Of course, the two are all blocked,then I read from the fifofile

```
read -n1 < a.fifo
```

All are released and I only got one and the other char is missing...

My question is why it happened and how can I get the content from fifo file one by one without losing data?

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By doing `read -n1 < a.fifo`, you

1. Opened `a.fifo` for reading
2. Read one character
3. Closed `a.fifo`

Closing a fifo in either end, closes it in both ends.

Leave it open until you don't need it anymore.

```
exec 3< a.fifo    # open for reading, assign fd 3
read -r line1 <&3 # read one line from fd 3
read -r line2 <&3 # read one line from fd 3
exec 3<&-         # close fd 3
```

And at the other end:

```
exec 3> a.fifo       # open for writing, assign fd 3
printf 'hello\n' >&3 # write a line to fd 3
printf 'wolrd\n' >&3 # write a line to fd 3
exec 3>&-            # close fd 3
```

See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial for more on redirection